# discord.py - Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Embed' object has no attribute 'edit'

Tags: python, discord.py

Couldn't seem to find an answer for this anywhere, and don't know why it is happening as I've never  encountered it before.

Bit where message is edited:

```
for q in scq:
    q = json.loads(q)
    embed2=discord.Embed(title=q["question"], description=q["desc"], color=0x2f3136)
    await msg.edit(embed=embed2)
    m = await bot.wait_for('message', timeout=60, check=check)
    alist.append(m.content)
```

The message that is edited:

```
msg=discord.Embed(title=f"test1", description="test2", color=0x2f3136)
await ctx.send(embed=msg)
```

I think this is all the code necessary to show, though if you need to see more just say.

Comment: You can only edit a message object, not an embed object. Please paste the traceback of the error itself as well.

Comment: `msg` has a type discord.Embed from when it was initialized. There is no method for edit per documentation: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `discord.Embed` object is not editable.
But you can do something like this:

```
embed1 = discord.Embed(title='1')
embed2 = discord.Embed(title='2')
message = await ctx.send(embed=embed1)
await message.edit(embed=embed2)
```

In that case you're not editing the Embed, but you're editing the message changing the Embed in it.

## Your problem

Since you didn't provide the full Traceback, I can only imagine what the error was caused by:

- At line 4 in your code the `msg.edit()` call raises an error because of `msg` being a `discord.Embed` and not a `discord.Message` object.
- There's a `.edit()` call outside the code you posted.

## Documentation

- [`discord.Embed`'s methods](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed)

Comment: Ohh, I see. Should have paid more attention to the documentation. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Thanks also for the upvote.